# Maven: OutOfMemoryError - heap space

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea

**Problem:** I run `mvn clean install -DskipTest` and get

```
[ERROR] The system is out of resources.
[ERROR] Consult the following stack trace for details.
[ERROR] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

**More informaiton:**

- *Operation system:* OS X (16 GB RAM)
- *Java configurations:* located at `~/Libraries/Preferences/IntelliJIdea13/idea.vmoptins` and `Applications/IntelliJ\ Idea\ 13.app/bin/idea.vmoptions`

  -Xms256m
  -Xmx2048m
  -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
  -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
  -XX:+UseCompressedOops
- *MAVEN_OPTS:* `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2048M -XX:PermSize=92M -XX:MaxPermSize=384M"` located at `~/.bash_profile`
- *Intellij Idea maven opts:* `-xms256m -xmx2048 -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M`. I set them in `Default Settings` -> `MAven` -> `Runner` -> `VM Options`

**Question:** *How to solve?*

**Stacktrace:**

```
[ERROR] The system is out of resources.
[ERROR] Consult the following stack trace for details.
[ERROR] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Position$LineMapImpl.build(Position.java:139)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Position.makeLineMap(Position.java:63)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.getLineMap(Scanner.java:1113)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:512)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:550)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:804)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:727)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:279)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:270)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:87)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:554)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:161)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:605)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project com.conductor.thrift.client: Compilation failure
Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
```

Comment: please run it with `-e` and post the error stack

Comment: In which phase it runs out of memory? Is the maven compiler plugin or the tests.

Comment: @ssedano at one of the modules. Means it's already build few submodules and fails at the next

Comment: @JigarJoshi look at updated answer pls

Comment: looks like it goes OOM just in compile phase, to make sure nothing else is leaking, could you please run `mvn clean compile -e` once

Comment: @V_B execute $ echo $MAVEN_OPTS to make sure it is loaded. If not try running $ MAVEN_OPTS="-xms256m -xmx2048 -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M" mvn clean install -DskipTest

Comment: @ssedano `echo $MAVEN_OPTS` returns `-Xmx2048M -XX:PermSize=92M -XX:MaxPermSize=384M`

Comment: @JigarJoshi yes, `mvn clean compile -e` throw the same exception

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Java compiler plugin goes out of memory based on the comments above, to fix this you need to give Java compiler plugin more memory and to that inside your `pom.xml` add this

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <meminitial>512m</meminitial>
          <maxmem>1048m</maxmem>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```